# Codeigniter URI Class how can i use – hyphen instead _ underscore?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

i tried create some controllers, models and views with - hyphen, but i get php error always so i am using underscore right now.

so my url is:
http://localhost:8888/ci/index.php/get_artist_discography/artist_name

i would like be like that:
http://localhost:8888/ci/index.php/get-artist-discography/artist-name

its possible have urls with - hyphen in codeigniter?

my code:

/controllers:

```
    <?php 
include (APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');
class get_artist_discography extends REST_Controller {

    function artist_name_get(){

    $data = new stdClass();
    $this->load->model('artist_model');
    $data = $this->artist_model->getAll();$this->response($data, 200);


    }

}
```

/models:

```
  <?php 
class artist_model extends CI_Model {
    function getAll(){

        $q  = $this->db->query("SELECT artist_discography,artist_name from music");

        if($q->num_rows() > 0) {

            foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
                $data [] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can.

Normally CI produce url like this base_url/Controller_name/Method_name.

As you know controller name and method name cannot contain '-'(hyphen) so you cannot change their name.

What can you do is use router to show the correct controller with corresponding url.

Like you can write this code at your config/routes.php

```
$route['get-artist-discography/artist-name'] ='get_artist_discography/artist_name';
```

This will execute your `get_artist_discography` controller and `artist_name` method if your link is `http://localhost:8888/ci/index.php/get-artist-discography/artist-name`

You can learn more about [URI Routing at CI docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: Use $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE; in the config/routes.php instead. You don't have to add a route for each controller.

Answer (score 16):

if you're using Codeigniter 3 open your config/routes.php

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Yes if your controller and method name is same with URL ,only different with hyphen and underscore  and you using CI-3 you can use this solution.[Details here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#reserved-routes)