# URI Routing Codeigniter with "-" instead of "/"

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have routed some pages in codeigniter.

I have something like this:

> www.website/page/pages/details/

I wrote this code in routes.php

```
$route['page/(.*)'] = 'page/index/$1';
```

But I don't like this form of link with "/"

I want "-" insead of "/", something like this:

> www.website/page-pages-details

How to do that ?

Comment: Do the various components within the URI relate to logical navigational hierarchies within your application? Do you care about SEO at all?  If you answered yes to both of these, you should probably not do this.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385655/use-hyphen-instead-of-slash-or-underscore-in-routes

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692283/codeigniter-uri-class-how-can-i-use-hyphen-instead-underscore/30692640#30692640) why you cannot and why you can do that.